# Issue Printing Elements of 2 Dimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been working on debugging some code and have narrowed down my issue to a simple a problem that should be easy to solve but for some reason is evading me for the last several hours. The code I have below for displaying the values of a 2 dimensional array are not displaying the way I imagined they would. I am new to C++ so if the issue is simply fixed that wouldn't surprise me. At this point I am out of ideas on what is causing my problem. Any help would be more than appreciated!

This is some simplified code for showing a 2 dimensional array in a grid that is 3 characters by 3 characters.

```
char board[2][2];

board[0][0] = '1';
board[0][1] = '2';
board[0][2] = '3';
board[1][0] = '4';
board[1][1] = '5';
board[1][2] = '6';
board[2][0] = '7';
board[2][1] = '8';
board[2][2] = '9';

cout << board[0][0] << " ";
cout << board[0][1] << " ";
cout << board[0][2] << endl;
cout << board[1][0] << " ";
cout << board[1][1] << " ";
cout << board[1][2] << endl;
cout << board[2][0] << " ";
cout << board[2][1] << " ";
cout << board[2][2] << endl;
```

The text below is what the output of the above code looks like. For some reason the value 3 is not displaying in the first row, last column, as I'm thinking it should. Instead a 4 is in its place which is then followed by another 4 on next row in the first column. This same issue is seen in the last column of the second row where the 7 is in place of where I think a 6 should be, followed by another 7 on the third line first column.

```
1 2 4
4 5 7
7 8 9
```

Comment: You created a 2x2 array instead of a 3x3 array (i.e., you need `char board[3][3]`).

Comment: I knew it had to be simple, you are correct! Thanks for the help. Not sure whey I thought array size declarator started at 0 rather than 1.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ declaration

```
char board[2][2];
```

declares array of char with size 2x2. Indexation starts at 0, therefore all valid indexes are:

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

Writing to the array using index bigger than size-1 , i.e.

```
board[2][0] = '7';
```

is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

James Adkison provided the correct answer in a comment. For some reason I had thought that the array size declarator started at 0 rather than 1, so a 3x3 array needs to be declared with board[3][3] rather than board [2][2].